# how to get real time chat history using agora sdk

Tags: real-time, p2p, agora.io

how can I get all pervious real chat history from agora server ,I develop code for messaging but when I close the app and reopen the app do not get any message from peer to peer messaging mechanism. Please suggest any idea about what can I do?

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: yes , for that I use sqlite databse

Comment: In that case, it won't persist in case the app is uninstalled or logged into another mobile. Have you considered any solution for this scenario?